# How can I fix - Swiftui tabview focus error on tvOS 15.2

Tags: swift, swiftui, tvos, swiftui-tabview

In **tvOS 15.2**, when using tabView in scroll, it comes back when going from left to right. While **tvOS 14 and 16** don't have this issue, I'm facing this issue in 15.2.

You can see the gif :
https://gifyu.com/image/SmE5Q

*My code*

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var index: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
    
    
    ScrollView(showsIndicators: true) {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $index) {
                ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { item in
                    //PageContent(model: data[item])
                    Button {
                        
                    } label: {
                        Text("METIN ATALAY \(item)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
            .padding(.bottom, 0)
            .frame(width: UI.screenSize.width, height: UI.screenSize.height * 0.64)
            
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                Text("\(UUID().uuidString)")
            }
            


               Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    Text("\(UUID().uuidString)")
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct UI {
    static let screenBounds: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    static let screenSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: screenBounds.width, height: screenBounds.height)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `TabView` the below solution fixed my issue

```
VStack {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0..<data.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        PageContent(model: data[index])
                            .id(index)
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: pageIndex) { newValue in
                    withAnimation {
                        proxy.scrollTo(newValue, anchor: .leading)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.padding(.bottom)
            .frame(width: deviceSize.width, height: layout.getBannerHeight(by: deviceSize))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the example code for tvOS < 16

```
  func tvOS_Body() -> some View {
       return Group {
            VStack {
                ScrollViewRTL(axis: .horizontal) {
                    ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                        HStack(spacing: 0) {
                            ForEach(0..<data.count, id: \.self) { index in
                                PageContent(model: data[index])
                                    .id(index)
                            }
                        }
                        .onChange(of: pageIndex) { newValue in
                            withAnimation {
                                if LocalizationManager.language.forceLayoutRTL {
                                    bannerRTLIndex = (data.count - 1) - newValue
                                } else {
                                    bannerRTLIndex = newValue
                                }
                                
                                proxy.scrollTo(newValue, anchor: .leading)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.padding(.bottom)
                    .frame(width: deviceSize.width, height: layout.getBannerHeight(by: deviceSize))
            }
            
            PageControlView(numberOfPages: data.count,
                            currentIndex: $bannerRTLIndex,
                            isFocused: isFocused,
                            animation: .standard,
                            primaryColor: .AppColor.accent)
            .onLoad {
                if LocalizationManager.language.forceLayoutRTL {
                    bannerRTLIndex = data.count - 1
                }
                firstLoad = true
            }
        }
    }
```